# Interchange of a sum and integral

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have to compute the following integral:

$$N = -\frac{2\pi A}{h^2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \ln(1-ze^{-\beta pc})p\mathrm{d}p$$

Let's say $z << 1$. Thus:

$$\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$$

$$N = \frac{2\pi A}{h^2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}p\frac{z^n e^{-n \beta pc}}{n}p$$

Now it is convenient to use the following change of variables:

$$x = \beta pc$$

$$N = \frac{2\pi A}{(h \beta c)^2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x\frac{z^n e^{-n x}}{n}x$$

It's time to factorize the series:

$$N = \frac{2\pi A}{(h \beta c)^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-x} \mathrm{d}x$$

But I saw in the provided solution that I am missing a factor of three on the series, as it is stated to be:

$$N = \frac{2\pi A}{(h \beta c)^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^3} \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-x} \mathrm{d}x$$

**From where is this to the power of 3 coming?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you went from $e^{-nx}$ to $e^{-x}$ without doing a proper change of variable. If $y=nx$ then the $x$ that you have next to the exponential becomes $y/n$ and $dx$ becomes $dy/n$. Therefore you have two extra $1/n$ factors